# Waiting for a js alert using watir-webdriver

Tags: watir-webdriver

I am using watir-webdriver to drive a test run of a web application.

The page in question responds to an input change with a confirm, followed by a page-churn, followed by an alert.

** UPDATE **

I have tried the following but I get a `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnhandledAlertError` that starts in the confirm block.

```
require "watir-webdriver/extensions/alerts"

b.alert do
  b.confirm(true) do
    b.checkbox(:index => 1).set
  end
end
```

** END UPDATE **

However adding the following (after the input change):

```
browser.driver.switch_to.alert.accept
```

will dismiss the first confirm no problem...

Unfortunately due to the page-churn trying the same line to dismiss the following alert raises a

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoAlertPresentError
```

as the alert hasn't happened yet.

My work-around is to add the following method to Watir::Browser

```
def get_alert (timeout = 300)
  Watir::Wait.until(timeout) {
    begin
      driver.switch_to.alert
    rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoAlertPresentError
    end
  }
end
```

and run all alert handling through

```
browser.get_alert
```

Is there a better/built-in way of doing this?

** UPDATE **

One benefit of my work-around is it allows me to handle alerts procedurally rather than with the harder to read (or generate) blocks within b.alert/b.confirm

** END UPDATE **

Thanks in advance,
Arth

Answer (score 2):

As per the [dialogs](http://watirwebdriver.com/javascript-dialogs/) page on the watir-webdriver site ->

```
require "watir-webdriver/extensions/alerts"

browser.confirm(true) do
  browser.button(:value => 'Confirm').click
end #=> 'the confirm message'
```

So, in your specific case instead of calling `browser.driver.switch_to.alert.accept` or `browser.get_alert` you should be able to call the above.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that the code inside the do above is going to be whatever causes the alert to appear.  The example given above happens to be from the rspec tests for this which use a test HTML page that has a button with a value of 'Confirm', which causes a confirm alert to occur when clicked.   That line of code will have to change into whatever action it is that causes the confirm dialog in your case.

Comment: Thank you... but perhaps I should have made clear I am aware of the dialogs page and have tried this approach with no success.
As I mention in my qu, I have a confirm, followed by a page load, followed by an alert which is causing more trouble. I will update it to make this more clear...

Answer (score 0):

hard to know if this will work without having access to your page to try it, but have you considered trying something like this?

```
require "watir-webdriver/extensions/alerts"

b.alert do
  b.checkbox(:index => 1).set
  browser.driver.switch_to.alert.accept
  #possibly a wait here...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The newer [Alerts API](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Alert) has the standard waiting methods, so you can now do:

```
browser.alert.when_present.ok
```